# How can I intercept and stop the thunderbird send mail event?

Tags: javascript, email, xul, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stop Email From Sending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504943/stop-email-from-sending)

I need to intercept the send email event in Thunderbird, and **prevent the sending** of the email if certain conditions are met. I have managed to intercept the event with the code below, but it always sends the message after the handler, regardless of return value, or if an exception is thrown.

```
var composerContainer = function () {
  return {
    sendEventHandler : function (event) {
      //.....
      return false;
    }
  }
}();
window.addEventListener( "compose-send-message", composerContainer.sendEventHandler, true );
```

I can access and modify the contents of the message, but I have no way of stopping the sending of the message.

Comment: Oops, found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504943/stop-email-from-sending